# Force.com IDE deployment alternative

Tags: deployment, ide, mavensmate

When you deploy your code using the Force.com IDE you get the following overview:

[image: Eclipse deployment screen]

Using Mavensmate, I don't get this overview when deploying:

[image: Mavensmate deployment]

Is there a way to get a Force.com IDE-like overview of the status of my components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want to know if you're overwriting, creating or deleting the selected metadata piece ?

I don't know how to get that in Mavens Mate, and I do see how it could be useful.

[I've opened up a feature request issue over on the MavensMate Github Repository here.](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/239) but that of course holds no guarantee for when, or even if, the feature will be added.

Answer (score 3):

That functionality does not exist in MavensMate at this time. One way you can get an idea of what will be different is to setup two projects in the IDE, one for the source, one for the destination. Ensure both have pulled down the appropriate metadata and then you can use a regular diff tool to compare the folders. Most graphical tools will make it easy to see what files are the same (i.e. won't be overwritten, yellow in the Eclipse summary) and what files only exist in the source (green).

Deleting is a slightly different matter, but if you don't know what you're deleting with a deployment then you have much bigger problems than missing a summary.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; this is actually how I compare them at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I just put the source under local version control (I prefer mercurial) and after every deployment I do a commit. That way, when the next deployment is due the mercurial GUI (like SourceTree or TortoiseHG) shows you clearly which files were changed, added or deleted.